# Is it possible to place a service in a subpackage?

Tags: android, android-manifest

My [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is only working if I have the MyService.java in a package like

```
com.test.app
```

, but NOT in a subpackage like

```
com.test.app.services.MyService
```

In the manifest I tried declaring it with

```
<service android:name=".services.MyService" />
```

or fully qualified

```
<service android:name="com.test.app.services.MyService" />
```

but neither way worked. I am using subpackages for a better structure of my files. So can I really not put my service file in a subpackage or am I missing something here?

(I am working with the Expansion Downloader Library provided by the Android team. This involves implementing a simple service.)

Comment: You should be able to just fine. How is your Service "not working"? How are you starting your service?

Comment: I am subclassing the DownloaderService as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html#DownloaderService), so I am not starting the service myself...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put it in whatever namespace you want.

Beyond subclassing `DownloaderService` you need to read the rest of the document, including [Starting the download](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html#Download). Of particular interest is this line:

```
// Start the download service (if required)
int startResult = DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(this,
                pendingIntent, SampleDownloaderService.class);
```

Note that you need to provide your custom `Service` class here.

Comment: This is very weird. I am providing my custom Service class, and as I said, it is all functioning (incl. a test download from the Google Play servers), but only if the service is in the main package...

Comment: @Till I have exactly the same problem. Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: @theV0ID If I remember correctly I actually ended up keeping it in the main package...

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

I've done this many times.  Chances are there's something else going on.  The first thing I'd check is to make sure your `Intent` is properly constructed.

Comment: I am subclassing the DownloaderService as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html#DownloaderService), so I am not starting the service myself...

Comment: @Till That's your problem.  Just because you've sub-classed the other service doesn't mean that it gets magically started when `DownloaderService` gets started.  That would be bad for a variety of reasons.  You'll need to start your `Service` yourself.

Comment: No, it is getting started by the DownloaderLibrary (for Expansion Files), but only if it is in the main package declared in the manifest `package="com.test.app"`

Comment: @Till See the answer @kabuko gives below.  That class is hiding the construction of the `Intent`, but that's the key thing here.